# Entity Framework Core not detecting model properties (type and maxlength) for Equals on string, rendering nvarchar(4000) instead of varchar(10)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a piece of EF Core code that queries by `Id` generically, so the type could vary from string to int. In order to handle that in a base class we use the `.Equals` function.

```
var models = CreateDbSetModel(dbcontext);
return await models.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => id.Equals(x.Id));
```

We also have the model configured to have the string in this instance set to `HasMaxLength(10)` and `IsUnicode`:

```
entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode()
            .HasMaxLength(10);
```

and

```
entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Id)
             .HasColumnName("MyCol")
             .HasDefaultValue();
```

However, EF is rendering the SQL as:

```
WHERE @__id_0 = [x].[MyCol]',N'@__id_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__id_0=N'ABC12345'
```

The column is VARCHAR(10) and the param is NVARCHAR(4000).

So it is picking up the column name attribute (MyCol), but seems to be missing the `HasMaxLength` and `IsUnicode` attributes and going with SQL Server autoparameterization as mentioned in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx

Comment: `id` is a query parameter, it isn't bound to the same schema as the table. If you want to force these options on the query parameter, you would probably have to wrap it in a `SqlParameter` and be explicit about the type and max length

Comment: I am doing this in a generic query method, if I use an explicit == it works and renders with varchar(10), but with the Equals function it seems unable to pick up and render the type. Unfortunately, the == is not available on a generic type. I have also swapper the params to be x.Id.Equals(id) to no avail.

Comment: You could use reflection to build the predicate, so it is still generic and you can use the `==` operator

Comment: I do not see problem here. Do you have performance issues?

Comment: When your param type doesn't not match the column type you are comparing to, it tends to not use the index due to conversion.

Comment: Andrew, I have some other code in a different project, that I might be able to use for that, thanks for the suggestion, I will experiment with it. It does feel like a bug in EF Core though, it picks up the other model properties to render the sql correctly, but not this. We are in an older version with this project, so maybe it's fixed by now.

Comment: @JohanBotha, why do not to use `FindAsync(id)` in your case? It should be better and faster solution.

Comment: "When your param type doesn't not match the column type you are comparing to, it tends to not use the index due to conversion. " there's no conversion necessary between `NVARCHAR(4000)` and `NVARCHAR(10)`  They are the same type.

Comment: @David, it was NVARCHAR(4000) to VARCHAR(10), it was not clear enough, I will edit my question. I am trying to get EF Core when it is rendering the Equal function, to honor my model properties. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv , good idea, I will use it in some places. Unfortunately, it is not my schema and I cannot guarantee that the id will be the primary key ...

Comment: Well, you can always generate FirstOrDefault call dynamically.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I think that will be it in the end. Hopefully this bug is resolved in the newer version, I will have a look at it in my new framework I am building on 6, we are already doing a lot of dynamic stuff there, but might be dynamically calling equals, so I will need to make sure we don't have the same issue there. Otherwise I might have to fix it myself and do a pull request. Thank you for all your help.